# How to keep only a subset of SQL statements using Python

Tags: python, sql

Assuming that I want to process a SQL query in Python that looks like below:

```
query = """
SELECT a, b, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v='efg' or n='543')) THEN f END) AS feature_1, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=120 AND (v='efg' or n='528')) THEN f END) AS feature_2, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=189 AND (v='efg' or n='541')) THEN f END) AS feature_3 FROM table_a
"""
```

How can I filter out any unwanted statement in `SELECT` clause? For example, assume that I want to keep only columns `a`, `feature_1` and `feature_3` (i.e. `cols=['a', 'feature_1', 'feature_2']`). The desired output would be:

```
desired_output = 
"""
SELECT a, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v="efg" or n="543")) THEN f END) AS feature_1, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=189 AND (v="efg" or n="541")) THEN f END) AS feature_3 FROM table_a
"""
```

Comment: Just `SELECT` the columns you want.  I don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the coulmns part and the filter the columns, then build the new query from the filtered columns.

NOTE: the following code is case sensitive and you may have to change it to make it more flexible, but it will work for the data you have provided.

I have also added line breaks in the new query, to make the output more readable.

```
import re
query = """
SELECT a, b, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v="efg" or n="543")) THEN f END) AS feature_1, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=120 AND (v="efg" or n="528")) THEN f END) AS feature_2, SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=189 AND (v="efg" or n="541")) THEN f END) AS feature_3 FROM table_a
"""
cols_keep = ['a', 'feature_1', 'feature_2']
# extract the columns part
parts_sql = re.search('(SELECT)(.+?)(FROM)(.*)', query)
if parts_sql:
    cols = parts_sql.group(2)
    parts_cols = cols.split(",")
    parts_cols_keep = []
    # filter
    for col in parts_cols:
        col_name = col.split()[-1] # extract column name/alias
        if(col_name in cols_keep):
            parts_cols_keep.append(col)
    # build SQL
    query = "SELECT " + ",\n".join(parts_cols_keep) + "\nFROM " + parts_sql.group(4)
print(query)
```

Output:

```
SELECT  a,
 SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v="efg" or n="543")) THEN f END) AS feature_1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=120 AND (v="efg" or n="528")) THEN f END) AS feature_2
FROM  table_a
```

---

If your columns contain `,` you could use `,\n` to separate columns in the original query:

```
import re
query = """
SELECT
SUBSTR(a, 1, 2) as a,
b,
SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v="efg" or n="543")) THEN f END) AS feature_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=120 AND (v="efg" or n="528")) THEN f END) AS feature_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=189 AND (v="efg" or n="541")) THEN f END) AS feature_3
FROM table_a
"""
cols_keep = ['a', 'feature_1', 'feature_2']
# extract the columns part
parts_sql = re.search('(SELECT)((.|\n)*)(FROM)(.*)', query, re.MULTILINE)
if parts_sql:
    cols = parts_sql.group(2)
    parts_cols = cols.split(",\n")
    parts_cols_keep = []
    # filter
    for col in parts_cols:
        col_name = col.split()[-1]
        if(col_name in cols_keep):
            parts_cols_keep.append(col)
    # build SQL
    query = "SELECT " + ",\n".join(parts_cols_keep) + "\nFROM " + parts_sql.group(4)
print(query)
```

Output:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(a, 1, 2) as a,
SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=150 AND (v="efg" or n="543")) THEN f END) AS feature_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN (a-b=0 AND f-g<=120 AND (v="efg" or n="528")) THEN f END) AS feature_2
FROM FROM
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, assuming that I have some more complex cases with `substr()` etc, I assume that `parts_cols = cols.split(",")` won't work. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use ``,\n`` to separate the columns in the original query, then you can use that to split. Makes it also more readable, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am still a bit concerned as the select query contains a lot of statements/columns (approximately 1-2K), therefore I am not able to process the text and -manually- add new line after each column

Comment: Essentially, the query is stored in a single line, within a text file.